# One Event Handler for multiple text boxes which assign to different strings

Tags: c#

I have a view that has 70 or so text boxes.  I am using an object to store all the input so I can pass the input around my program.  What I have now is a save button and when this button is pressed each text box sends it's text to the object that holds all the input.

I want to change this implementation to have the text box send it's text to the object after the cursor leaves the text box.  I just don't want to write one event handler for each text box.

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/grusso/WritingaSingleEventHandlerforMultipleControls11242005233135PM/WritingaSingleEventHandlerforMultipleControls.aspx) site explains how to assign multiple text boxes to one event handler.  This works if each event needs to do that same thing.  Is their a way to assign multiple text boxes to one event handles but have each text bow upload it's contents to a different string?

I can't think of anything, so I am asking you all if you have any ideas.

Thanks,

dhoehna

Comment: You might be able to use the `Tag` property of the TextBox controls to determine which string to assign to in the event handler. Store something unique in the `Tag` property for each text box and use that to identify which text box it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with a dictionary:

```
textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler( textBox_LostFocus );

Dictionary<object, string> _contents = new Dictionary<object, string>( );
void textBox_LostFocus( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    _contents[ sender ] = ( sender as TextBox ).Text;
}
```

And to get the values as a list (in case you need it):

```
_contents.Select( kvp => kvp.Value ).ToList( );
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use `_contents[textBox]` to retrieve the value?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I assumed that the OP just needed a list of values for other components of his program.

Comment: @BlackBear why not use _contents.Values then? And also, I believe you have to check whether the sender is already a key or not. `if( _contents.ContainsKey( sender ) ) _contents[sender] ...; else _contents.Add( sender, ... );`

Comment: @clcto thank you, I wasn't aware of that property, but I just wanted a list with only the values. No need to check that, dictionaries automatically add the key if necessary

Comment: I like the solution.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @BlackBear "If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx... Ah, nevermind I just noticed the key phrase `a get operation`

Comment: @BlackBear yeah, I'm dumb

Comment: @clcto no worries, happens :P

Answer (score 3):

Have a `Dictionary< TextBox, string >` or even `Dictionary< object, string >` and use the `sender` object as the key to get the string to assign to.